# Javascript update specific element in object array based on subset

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs

I understand that you should use setstate to update state in React.  I have an array of objects in state and I would like to update a specific element.  How can I do that.  My data and code is the following:

```
var trans = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6"),
    "transid" : 1,
    "acct" : "acct1",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category1",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 2,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category2",
    "amount" : 103
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c152g2"),
    "transid" : 3,
    "acct" : "acct3",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category3",
    "amount" : 103
}]

  let transFilter=[];

    trans.forEach(function(el){
        if(parseInt(el.transid).indexOf(parseInt(1))!=-1)
        transFilter.push(el);
    });

    transFilter.category = "category4";

//this is where I'm not sure how to just update the corresponding record to
//the one in transFilter for tmpTrans; the data in trans is a copy of the data in tmpTrans
           this.setState({tmpTrans: transFilter}, function () {
           console.log(tmpTrans);
            });
```

Comment: Can you post the actual React code you're working with? You're correct that calling `setState` in React is the correct way of updating React specific state, it sounds and looks like from your code that you're simply asking how to update an item in an array, regardless of React

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I wanted to provide the code I'm referencing.  It is more of a javascript question, except for the fact that I need to do my update in set state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a a fairly straightforward function you can use to create a modified array.

Consider the following array of items:

```
var data = [
  { id: 1, category: 'sports' }, 
  { id: 2, category: 'movies' }
]
```

If you want to change the category of item with id of 2 you can map over your array and use `Object.assign` to create a copy of your object with the new category, if the id matches:

```
var newData = data.map(item => {
  if (item.id === 2) {
    return Object.assign({}, item, { category: 'food' })
  }
  return item
})
```

Now with your newly minted data you can simply set the state:

```
this.setState({ data: newData })
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and works, but is this the best way to do this?  I'm somewhat new to React/Javascript and I was just wondering if there is a way to avoid doing all the looping  in cases where my data set is big.  I really just need to update one record and I know in advance what it is.  This is just a conceptual question.

Comment: Yes an no. Because your data is in an array, the only way to know ahead of time which item to update, is to know the index ahead of time. This is usually impossible because to store the indexes you would need now another data structure. You could instead store you data in an object and access the item using the key directly. Also `map` is a very general way of doing this. you could use a combination of `find` and `slice` to possibly skip some iterations

Comment: That being said, your bottleneck is very likely not to be iterating through a large array. If that actually becomes the case you probably don't want to be storing such large arrays in memory anyways.

Comment: Makes sense. That's what I was thinking, but this works for now. I will probably come back to it and see what can be changed. Thanks again.

Comment: Why use `return Object.assign(...)` instead of  `item.category = 'food'`?